# Magento : 1 Showing New Products of Particular category on page

Tags: frontend, products, new-products, product-listing

Am working on Magento 1 Store

I want to show only new products of particular category on a page.
Suppose i have category of shirts so i want to show only 8 new products of that category on page.

i tried to use this block to show only category products but its not respecting the product limit.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="8" category_id="43" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="CATEGORY_ID" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column_count="5" products_count="10"}}
```

**Note** : Replace CATEGORY_ID with numeric category id.

Comment: Thanks for help sir, but on frontend product count is not being respected as it shows all the products of that category.

Comment: can you add this code on you phtml

<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
 $_productCollection->clear()->setPageSize($this->getData('products_count'))->load();
?>